# Android ImageView: dynamic selector doesn't work within HorizontalScrollView

Tags: selector, state, imagebutton, horizontalscrollview

I've a problem with HorizontalScrollView and the ImageButton (also ImageView) contained in it. I've assigned a drawable selector dynamically when the HorizontalScrollView is populated.

All is ok cause you can click and fire OnClickListener. The problem is with the items state. When the ImageButton is clicked (touched screen), shows the correct drawable, but when I take off the finger (untouch screen), shows the default image and not the pressed image.
The same problem occurs if I assign a static drawable selector (XML selector).

This is the code of the dynamic selector:

```
public static StateListDrawable setStateListDrawable(Context context, TypedArray images){
    
    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    
    try{
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},images.getDrawable(1));
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},images.getDrawable(1));
        states.addState(new int[] { },images.getDrawable(0));
    }catch(Exception e){
        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ID1", "array", context.getPackageName());
        images = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(id);
        
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},images.getDrawable(1));
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},images.getDrawable(1));
        states.addState(new int[] { },images.getDrawable(0));
    }
    
    return states;
}
```

And this is the HorizontalScrollView xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollSports"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
     
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/iwm_sports_container" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           
    </LinearLayout>
    
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved. I can't belive it!!!

I've put the "selected state" on the dynamic selector:

```
public static StateListDrawable setStateListDrawable(Context context, TypedArray images){

        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();

        try{
            states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},images.getDrawable(1));
            states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},images.getDrawable(1));
            **states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_selected},images.getDrawable(1));**
            states.addState(new int[] { },images.getDrawable(0));
        }catch(Exception e){
            int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ID1", "array", context.getPackageName());
            images = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(id);

            states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},images.getDrawable(1));
            states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},images.getDrawable(1));
            **states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_selected},images.getDrawable(1));**
            states.addState(new int[] { },images.getDrawable(0));
        }

        return states;
    }
```

And I changed the attribute descendantFocusability on the LinearLayout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollSports"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/iwm_sports_container" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"**>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Cheers!!!

P.D: Sorry for my english!!!

Comment: just faced similar issue but in the list and unfortunately, not able to observe neither pressed, neither selected bg's on list items with HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Where to add this **setStateListDrawable** method and how to call it.